# How to secure HTTP traffic inside a WinForms application from sniffing

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

What are the methods used to secure HTTP traffic inside a WinForms application from sniffing.

I want to ensure that all HTTP traffic originating from say the WebRequest is not directly visible to someone using a sniffing application such as Fiddler.

Apart from using HTTPS are there any alternatives for sending web traffic out of a WinForms application that is unsniffable?

Comment: You can't make it unsiffable, you can only make it incomprehensible to eavesdroppers.

Comment: All of your answers are great! Basically I can encrypt data using a public key on WinForms, and then transmit over HTTPS.

Comment: If there are great answers, up vote them...

Comment: FYI I'm the only person that upvoted answers in this question Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a VPN connection to the webserver, and then route the traffic over that?

You could create a SSH connection to a server that has a VPN tunnel to the webserver, then route all the traffic via SHH, then the VPN?

Comment: This question provides 2 ways to secure traffic between a Winforms Application and a Server in a Client/Server type scenario.

Comment: but VPN connection is system wide, not application wide. am I right ?

Comment: @mrid To most applications, a VPN looks like a network connection. Most VPN clients can be setup to be used in "gateway mode" (or similar) so that all traffic is routed via the VPN, but this doesn't have to be the case. I have a work VPN that only handles certain IP ranges, so most traffic can still route directly from my home office.

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt your payload but if you want the whole transmission secure HTTPS is the way to do it.

Comment: Encrypted text inside an encrypted layer? Possible overkill.

Comment: @Jeremy - I don't think you understood me: I ment to say that the content can be encrypted if you want to stick to HTTP, but a better solution is HTTPS. Then you don;t have to encrypt the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WCF as the communication tool behind your WinForms application then [this MSDN series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362.aspx) could be usesful. It describes a range of alternative security options in a good level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

Just using HTTPS isn't enough of course. You have to also have to make sure that the server at the other end of the HTTPS pipe is the server you expect with the correct certificate.

Otherwise someone using Fiddler (or something similar) can respond to your HTTPS requests with their own self signed certificate.

Fiddler has a feature where it acts as a proxy between the client and the HTTPS connected server. It uses its own self signed certificate to talk to the client and then uses HTTPS to talk to the remote server, proxying the data between them and allowing the user to see the plain text of the data. If the client isn't checking that the certificate at the other end is the right one, it never knows that the connection isn't actually secure.

And yes, you need to use HTTPS/SSL or some other form of encryption, as someone with admin rights on the local machine can see any data you send over the network, there is no other way of hiding it from them.

Comment: This is helpful information but it does not provide any alternative to HTTPS.